# Combo Box auto change

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a Combo Box linked to a cell that conducts Data Validation and pulls a wealth of information that is used to auto-populate a form with known data based on part number. The problem is, there are a couple part numbers that get tricky because, the part number that is displayed on the label is different than the part number in our inventory system.

When one of these part numbers are selected, the number is placed in Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“O6”). VBA is then programmed within a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)`as:

```
If Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“O6”) = “10021234” Then Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“O6”) = “10025678”
```

This updates all other cells that reference Sheet2 Cell O6 by changing their values from 10021234 to 10025678 except, the Combo Box continues to show 10021234 until `Worksheets(“Sheet1”).PrintOut` is called within a CommandButton event.

What I’m trying to do is, when one of these numbers are selected from the Combo Box, before it’s printed, preferably as soon as the affected number is selected, change the value of the Combo Box to match the value of Sheet2 Cell O6.

tldr;
I would like the value of the Combo Box to change when the value of it’s linked cell changes